# ExactStatsCache not working for distributed IDF

Tags: solr, similarity, solrcloud, tf-idf

I am using ExactStatsCache in SolrCloud (7.7.1) by adding following to 
solrconfig.xml file for all collections.

```
<statsCache class="org.apache.solr.search.stats.ExactStatsCache"/>
```

I restarted and indexed the 
documents of all collections after this change just to be sure.

However, when I do multi-collection query for these collections, the scores do not change before 
and after adding ExactStatsCache. By scores, I mean the score as field value in the response and not in the debug output. I am aware that there is one [open issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7759) for debug output not being correct for distributed query so I am not relying on that.

Do you know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: facing a similar issue, where did you place this line in config, as some inner tag or a parent tag, i mean inside query or something?

Comment: @Yatin I think I put it right under the <config> tag.

Answer (score 2):

I found out what the issue was. It was a silly one. I was not restarting all of my nodes in SolrCloud because of which the ExactStatsCache config change was not taking effect.